# Could we add an apikey value on NuGetDefaults.Config the same way as the NuGet.config file?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, config

I've been reading about NuGetDefaults.Config file in the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#nuget-defaults-file

My question is; Can I set apikey values with something like the command below or manually included in the NuGetDefaults.Config and it will work as well on the NuGet.config file?

nuget setapikey  -Source  [options]